# Create radio group using array adapter

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I want to create a group of radio buttons using array adapter.And i want to get the information that which one of them is selected and deselect the other buttons of selection of any button.Can anyone please help me in doing this

Comment: Are you trying to put Radio Buttons in a ListView?

Comment: pls post some code.. what have you done?

Comment: no i am trying to add radio button one by one in linear layout using array adapter.i am getting radio button as a view and then adding this to my linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
     <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Free Lancer"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Firm/companies"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </RadioGroup>
```